# Javascript multiple image change with button clicks

Tags: javascript, image, button

Ok, this is what I'm trying to do, it was too vague earlier so here's a better explanation, keep in mind I've only been programming pages for like 2 weeks now so any help is appreciated.

I need to create a HTML/JavaScript webpage that displays three images along with a caption (description) for each image.  For each image I need to also create a button that changes the first image to a different image on the same subject (and change the caption too). Also need to have a button that restores all three images back to the original images.

I got the coding to work so that one image would change to another on button click but then when I added my 2nd and 3rd coding nothing would work anymore.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/300x/159304.jpg";
return false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg" />
<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>

<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image1");
img.src="http://playerperspective.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/mike-tyson-3.jpg";
return false;
}

</script>

<body>
<img id="image1" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-    images/Sport/Pix/pictures/2008/10/31/1225454147507/Mike-Tyson-001.jpg" />
<button id="Click1" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change!</button>
</body>

<br>

<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image2");
img.src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Technology/Pix/pictures/2012/3/5/1330958259135/Halo-4-007.jpg";
return false;
}

</script>

<body>
<img id="image2" src="http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/halo-master- chief-1.jpg" />
<button id="Click2" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change!</button>
</body>

<br>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Chad and welcome to Stackoverflow. You mentioned in this post that you were "too vague" in your earlier question. This one is a little bit better, but I would suggest that you also post your code, or head over to jsfiddle.net and provide an example in your question to the problem that you are having. This will strengthen your answer so we can better help you and you can get an answer to your question! Hope this helps you a bit, and, welcome again to SO!

Comment: This is the coding I used for the first image switch, then I tried to replicate it while changing the img id and it made the rest of the code stop working:

Comment: <html> 
<head> 
<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/300x/159304.jpg";
return false;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg" />
<br><br><br>
<button id="clickme" onclick="changeImage();">Click to change image!</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @ChadThompson - put the code in your original question by editing it

Comment: Ok, that's the code I used on the first image and it worked fine, then when I tried to just replicate it and change the variable names for image2 and image3 the entire code stopped working.

Comment: @ChadThompson - When you say you are "trying to change the variable names" - can you also put that code in your question so we can see what you're trying to do to get the other images to work?

Comment: I'm sure something's wrong in my coding since this is the first time I've tried to do something like this, all the original images show up fine and the buttons are there, but they don't change when clicked.

Comment: I also removed the argument part out of the 2nd and 3rd coding before posting that, I tried tampering with using argument1 2 and 3 to get the different codes to work but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: When I try each image code individually they each work, but when I combine them into a list none of them work, is there a way I should combine all 3 scripts into one script or how should I list them so that they all work individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your page: Missing document type declaration, missing `title` tag, actual content HTML in `head` and multiple `body` tags. In addition to these, `changeImage()` is replaced in every `script` with a new one. Finally there will be only the last function, which changes the `src` for `#image2`.

If I've understood your question correctly, you need something like this:

The `script` in the `head`:

```
function changeImage (element) {
    var n,
        imageData = [
            [
                {
                    src: "http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 1.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/300x/159304.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 1.2"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    src: "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Sport/Pix/pictures/2008/10/31/1225454147507/Mike-Tyson-001.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 2.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://playerperspective.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/mike-tyson-3.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 2.2"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    src: "http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/halo-master-chief-1.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 3.1"
                },
                {
                    src: "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Technology/Pix/pictures/2012/3/5/1330958259135/Halo-4-007.jpg",
                    caption: "Caption for image 3.2"
                }
            ]
        ];
    if (element > -1) {
        document.getElementById('image' + element).src = imageData[element][1].src;
        document.getElementById('caption' + element).innerHTML = imageData[element][1].caption;
    } else {
        for (n = 0; n < imageData.length; n++) {
            document.getElementById('image' + n).src = imageData[n][0].src;
            document.getElementById('caption' + n).innerHTML = imageData[n][0].caption;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And the `body`:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="changeImage(-1);" >Click to restore all!</button>
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption0">Caption for image 1.1</h1>
        <button onclick="changeImage(0);">Click to change!</button>
        <img id="image0" src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/william-defoe.jpg" />
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption1">Caption for image 2.1</h1>
        <button onclick="changeImage(1);">Click to change!</button>
        <img id="image1" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Sport/Pix/pictures/2008/10/31/1225454147507/Mike-Tyson-001.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="caption2">Caption for image 3.1</h1>
        <button onclick="changeImage(2);">Click to change!</button>
        <img id="image2" src="http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/halo-master-chief-1.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the data for paths and captions is in the objects in nested array. This way they are separated from actual content, and the code is easier to maintain.

You didn't provide an example of the layout for the captions of the images, so I put caption information in `H1` tags above the image. Feel free to change the element and its position. Notice, that you can also use HTML-tags within caption texts.

However, there are some limitations and waste of CPU-time when executing this code: `imageData` is created by every click and only two different paths can be used per element.

I'd suggest you to have more object-oriented approach to the task. Please take a look at this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6mkr/2/), which demonstrates quite similar functionality, and is more flexible and maybe easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks very much for the lookover and help with the coding, I appreciate it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I didn't realize I could code all 3 scripts into one and thought I had to separate them each due to the layout (very new to this as I said), thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe my JSfiddle was too heavy =). Have you visited at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ , there you can find basics and also advanced information over JS, CSS, HTML and many more.

Comment: Would you mind, if I asked you to accept the answer. That way I earn some rep, and others in SO can see that your problem is solved.

Comment: My bad, haven't checked back here in a week but I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script>
        var dd = 5;
        var cnt = 0;
        function chng() {

            var rotator = document.getElementById('rr');  // change to match image ID
            var imageDir = 'Images/';                          // change to match images folder


            var images = ['2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg'];

            cnt++;

            var len = images.length;
            if (cnt < dd) {
                rr.src = imageDir + images[cnt];
            }
            else if (cnt == len) {
                rr.src = imageDir + images[0];
                cnt = 0;
            }
        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="Images/1.jpg" id="rr" height="500" width="650">

    <input type="button" value=" next. . " onclick="chng()" />
</body>
</html>
```